# Is there any way to execute a dynamic query in bigquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, google-bigquery, logic

Folks, I need to do a dynamic select in a table, using the variable after from, like this:
SELECT * FROM @table.

If anyone can do this otherway, please help!

tks!

I'm using this query below:

```
DECLARE id INT64;
    DECLARE contador INT64 DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE name_table STRING;
    DECLARE query STRING;       

    CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `crm-prod-254714.work.controle_tabelas`
    AS
    SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT('`', table_catalog, '.', table_schema, '.', table_name, '`') as tabela
                  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS ROWID
    FROM ntk.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;

    SET id = (SELECT MAX(ROWID) FROM `crm-prod-254714.work.controle_tabelas`);

    WHILE (contador <= id) DO

    SET name_table = (SELECT tabela FROM `crm-prod-254714.work.controle_tabelas` WHERE rowid = 1);

    SET QUERY = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', name_table, ';');

    EXECUTE QUERY;

    SET contador = contador+1;

    END WHILE
```

Comment: A variable name must have a single @ as the first character in T-SQL

Comment: Have you checked out new scripting functionalities in bigquery https://www.google.com/amp/s/cloudblog.withgoogle.com/products/data-analytics/command-and-control-now-easier-in-bigquery-with-scripting-and-stored-procedures/amp/

Comment: Denis, if I put @ before, it doesn't works...

Comment: sramalingam, I've checked this before asking right here, but doesn't say anything about execute a variable ):

Comment: You cannot do this purely in BigQuery, but you can easily do this in any client of your choice! Have you considered? Such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60325569/making-ipython-bigquery-magic-function-sql-query-dynamic

Answer (score 0):

As of 5/20/2020, BigQuery [released](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#May_20_2020) dynamic SQL feature for you to achieve the goal.

> Dynamic SQL is now available as a beta release in all BigQuery regions. Dynamic SQL lets you generate and execute SQL statements dynamically at runtime. For more information, see [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate).

For your scenario, you only need to make change to one line:

```sql
    EXECUTE QUERY;
=>
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE QUERY;
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you want, but you can create a stored procedure (routine) that uses dynamic SQL and then use a Scheduled Query to execute the proc.

The proc would [DELETE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#delete_statement) (or [TRUNCATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#truncate_table_statement)) then [INSERT...SELECT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#insert_examples).

Here is an example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `my-dw.ticket_15_predictions.output_latest_proc`()

BEGIN

DECLARE tablename STRING;
DECLARE sql STRING;

-- Use truncate.  There is no cost associated with it. It does count towards quotas and limits though.
-- DELETE FROM `my-dw.ticket_15_predictions.output_latest_tbl` WHERE 1 = 1;
TRUNCATE TABLE `my-dw.ticket_15_predictions.output_latest_tbl`;

SET tablename = (SELECT table_name
FROM ticket_15_predictions.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_name LIKE 'output_%' 
AND table_name != 'output_latest_tbl'
AND creation_time = (SELECT MAX(creation_time) FROM ticket_15_predictions.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name LIKE 'output_%' AND table_name != 'output_latest_tbl') LIMIT 1);

SET sql = CONCAT('INSERT `my-dw.ticket_15_predictions.output_latest_tbl`(visit_date, key, predicted_quantity, predicted_on_visit_date) SELECT * FROM `my-dw.ticket_15_predictions.',tablename,'`;');

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql; 
END;
```

In this case, I have 100+ tables with the format output_YYYY-MM-DD, so I only want the latest one.  I insert into a table called output_latest_tbl which can be used by Dataprep, Looker (Studio), and other tools that only handle tables and views.

The BigQuery scheduled query just has this:

`CALL` my-dw.ticket_15_predictions.output_latest_proc`();`